# google earth tour error

Tags: google-earth

In the past I had successfully created several Google Earth tours complete with audio and animation. As best I can remember, I looked at one of my tours 2weeks ago? and things were working fine.

But I look at the tours now on both my local machine and my host web server and the google earth tours have disappeared. When I look in firebug at where the code should be, I see the following error:

Failed to process gadget http://code.google.com/apis/kml/embed/tourgadget.xml. Reason: Unable to retrieve spec for... code.google.com/apis/kml/embed/tourgadget.xml. HTTP error 404

I have not changed anything within my code, so am completely at a loss.

Can anyone share what might have happened or what I need to do to get my GEs going again?
My web site is www.kavelookout.com...See www.kavelookout.com/fingers.html for where a tour should be.

UPDATE:

I believe this is the GE tour gadget code I need...

http://www.gmodules.com/ig/creator?synd=open&url=http://code.google.com/apis/kml/embed/tourgadget.xml

but as you can see, clicking on the 'More info...' link takes me to... google.com/ig/directory?synd=open&url=http://…

Does anyone know why GE Gadgets is not working at this time? Or what link I should be using to embed GE Tours? Can anyone confirm that GE Tours are having a problem, or is it me?

Much Thanks,

k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out.

The embed code that was generated in the past was...
script src="http:// www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://code.google.com/apis/kml/embed/tourgadget.xml

I'm not sure why or when it changed, but I found that the GE Tour gadget at this URL...
http://www.gmodules.com/ig/creator?synd=open&url=http://dl.google.com/developers/maps/tourgadget.xml

...now generates this new embed code...notice the differences...
script src="//www.gmodules.com/ig/ifr?url=http://dl.google.com/developers/maps/tourgadget.xml

Again, I'd love to know why things changed, but am happy to know there is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should notice that the pages you're trying to process are no longer available, so, that's the nature of the error.

Check the link, it sais that the page is not being found, that's why you're getting a 404 error.

Comment: Thanks for your help Nuxy,

I believe this is the GE tour gadget code I need... 
http://www.gmodules.com/ig/creator?synd=open&url=http://code.google.com/apis/kml/embed/tourgadget.xml

but as you can see, clicking on the 'More info...' link takes me to...
http://www.google.com/ig/directory?synd=open&url=http://code.google.com/apis/kml/embed/tourgadget.xml

Does anyone know why GE Gadgets is not working at this time? Or what link I should be using to embed GE Tours?

Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea about that, I'm sorry :S